# Proper regular expression in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a table called regions and column region which is not empty. There is a text in it, which is 'Tashkent'. I am trying to access it with expression input. Here is my code:

```
select * from regions where lower(region) ~ '[t]{1,}[k]{1,}';
```

As you can see, I am trying to get the word which contains letters `t` and `k` consecutively. According to my expression: `[t]{1,}[k]{1,}` above it should return text `'Tashkent'`, but not returning. Is my code correct. Can you suggest an alternative code to get word 'Tashkent' knowing that I have letters `t` and `k`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the characters between `t` and `k`

```
select lower('Tashkent') ~ 't{1,}.*k{1,}';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

Comment: Yes, working. Thank you so much. I looked for much sources to know more about POSIX and expressions separately; even documentation of PSQL, but not much there. Can you please suggest any source to lean? Thank you one more time.

Comment: @ShohruhAbduakhatov: The term to search for is _regular expression_

Comment: @ShohruhAbduakhatov: [Postgresql manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Answer (score 1):

1) If i understand what you want regex is not necessary :

```
     select * from regions where region ilike '%t%k%'
```

2) if you want absolutely do this with regex :

- your request : 't{1,}.*k{1,}' return true only if you have "tk" in your string for example "azerty ttk qwerty".
- A good solution is Clodoaldo Neto's solution :  lower(region) ~ 't{1,}.*k{1,}'
- You can also remove lower function with region ~ '[tT]{1,}.*[kK]{1,}'
- and finally {1,} can be replaced by + : region ~ '[tT]+.*[kK]+'

Comment: Nice. Good answer. Thanx, much useful things to learn in a single answer. Thanx a lot